# Яндекс-касса на самописном сайте, файл paymentAviso.php

Tags: php, phpmailer, яндекс-касса

Файлы `checkOrder.php` и `paymentAviso.php` - стандартный код который предоставляет яндекс. В `paymentAviso.php`, если хэши совпадают то формирую и отсылаю `email: include('config.php');`

```
require_once('../classes/class.phpmailer.php');
$hash = md5($_REQUEST['action'].';'.$_REQUEST['orderSumAmount'].';'.$_REQUEST['orderSumCurrencyPaycash'].';'.$_REQUEST['orderSumBankPaycash'].';'.$configs['shopId'].';'.$_REQUEST['invoiceId'].';'.$_REQUEST['customerNumber'].';'.$configs['ShopPassword']);

if (strtolower($hash) != strtolower($_REQUEST['md5'])){ 
    $code = 1;
}
else {
    $code = 0;
}
if($code == 0 ){
    require_once "../config.php";
    $array = array("status_payment"=>'PaymentSuccess');
        DB::update(DB::updateSql("count_zakaz",$array),$array,$_REQUEST['orderNumber']);
        $subject_user = "Оформлен заказ с сайта тест.рф №" . $_REQUEST["orderNumber"];
        $message_user = "<html>
                                <body>
                                    Здравствуйте, " . $_REQUEST['custName'] . "!<br><br>
                                    Ваш заказ № " . $_REQUEST["orderNumber"] . " от " . $today . " принят и оплачен.<br><br>
                                    Сумма заказа: " . $_REQUEST['orderSumAmount'] . " руб.<br><br>
                                    У вас есть вопросы? Позвоните нам по телефону или воспользуйтесь формой обратной связи.<br><br><br>
                                    Спасибо за покупку!<br><br><br><br>
                                    С уважением, тестовый " . "«Тест»" . "<br><br>
                                    Тел: ".DB::select('settings')[0]['phone']."
                                </body>
                        </html>";
        //foreach ($maillist as $mailer) {
        $mailer = "test2015@gmail.com";
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->From = 'test@test.ru';      // от кого //Почта клиента
        $mail->FromName = "Теста";   // от кого
        $mail->IsHTML(true);        // выставляем формат письма HTML
        $mail->Subject = $subject_user;  // тема письма;
        $mail->Body = $message_user;
        $mail->AddAddress($mailer); // кому - адрес, Имя
        $mail->Send();
        //}
}
print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    print '<paymentAvisoResponse performedDatetime="'. $_REQUEST['requestDatetime'] .'" code="'.$code.'" invoiceId="'. $_REQUEST['invoiceId'] .'" shopId="'. $configs['shopId'] .'"/>';
```

Проблема в том , что скрипт почему-то дублирует письмо каждые 45 минут :(
Кто знает, подскажите, где тут что неверно или может чего-то не хватает, из-за чего яндекс сервер постоянно (каждые 45 минут) отправляет запрос?

Answer (score 1):

Сервис Яндекс периодически проверяет "хост-сайт" на наличие доступности ресурса `check`, а может и `aviso` тоже, вот и получается, что к Вам периодически поступают запросы.